# vb.net's AddHandler is what? A method of some call?

Tags: vb.net-2010

In VB.net, I have to use AddHandler (to add handler function dynamically) without the brackets.
However if I use brackets like:

```
AddHandler(MyBtn.Click, AddressOf MyBtn_Click)
```

It does not work. The call must be without brackets.
Is there any equivalent syntax for calling AddHandler using brackets?
Is AddHandler different from subroutine or a function (method) of some class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a *statement*, not a function call.  Just like Return.

You wouldn't do

```
Return(x)
```